# Standard Android API for Video Output (HDMI, etc...)

Tags: android, video, media, android-mediaplayer, hdmi

Is there a specific standard API for making the videos from my propietary media player output to different video output connections that Android phones have?

Motorola ATRIX has the mini-hdmi and samsung uses other interface... is there a simple way? standard way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard API. Some vendors published hdmi API (like Motorola, but only for couple of devices), for the rest you cant do much since the hdmi OS service that uses ioctls and /dev/ access is not accessible for unsigned apps.